# Не включается ПК.Что делать?

Tags: пк

не давно оставил компьютер включённым, забыл про него. Через 30мин возвращаюсь он уже выключен, но смотрю сзади светодиоды горят и моргают вокруг кнопки включения. Они и должны гореть, но только в включенном состоянии и не моргать. (я естественно выключил пк из розетки, что бы не горело). Подключил, и пк не включается. Так же день назад после этого события менял процессор на пк. Но всё целый день работало, к тому же поставил обратно старый процессор, всё равно не включается. Посмотрел в инете. И насколько я понял проблема может быть в блоке питания, в самой кнопке ВКЛ, и в материнке. Но у меня нет возможности проверить, так как нет спец аппаратов и запасных комплектующих. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Явно не по теме (этот вопрос никак не связан с темой Stack Overflow на русском)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Проверить блок питания можно так:

https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Если блок рабочий, то отверткой на материнке попробуйте замкнуть Power SW (должны быть в нижней части материнки). Если блок рабочий, а материнка в подключенном состоянии при такой манипуляции не стартанет, то скорее всего мертва она. Да и опять, же, с нерабочим блоком не думаю что у вас диоды бы горели.

Comment: А из-за чего к примеру может сломаться материка?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Причин настолько много, включая "просто так сломалась", что нет смысла особого об этом думать. В трети случаев даже при диагностике вам не скажут почему материнка сдохла.